# the inputs Will not be displayed from php file to android screen

Tags: php, android

I wrote the following code  with the help of [this site](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89). But because I use `PHPRunner` in my device. I changes the `url` as follows:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/connection.php`

But when I click on the button to display the inputs from `php server`,  the inputs Will not be displayed from `php` file to android screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView content;
    EditText fname, email, login, pass;
    String Name, Email, Login, Pass;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );
        fname      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        email      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        login      =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginname);
        pass       =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


        Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try{

                    // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                    GetText();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    content.setText(" url exeption! " );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Create GetText Metod
    public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Get user defined values
        Name = fname.getText().toString();
        Email   = email.getText().toString();
        Login   = login.getText().toString();
        Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/connection.php");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
        content.setText( text  );

    }
```

And

```
<?php 

       $name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);
       $user   = urldecode($_POST['user']);
       $email  = urldecode($_POST['email']);
       $pass   = urldecode($_POST['pass']);

       print " ==== POST DATA =====
       Name  : $name
       Email : $email
       User  : $user
       Pass  : $pass"; 

 ?>
```

Comment: Your code can not work as you do network operations on the main gui thread. You have to use a Thread or AsyncTask. Do not use StrictMode.

Comment: `to display the inputs from php server`. No. You mean `to display the output -the print- from php script.

Answer (score 0):

You make this on your localhost. Check your address in CMD with command **ipconfig**. Then change address from *127.0.0.1* to adders of your computer. You have to known that also your emulator and Android device do not work in localhost. You have to use IP of your computer.

In my case it is 192.168.103

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and It will work. Only you add the following code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```